# Server goes down after every few hours - No route to host

Tags: linux, ssh, security, hetzner

I have a Ubuntu machine, it keep going down after some(10-15) hours. It returns the error as no route to host when I try to SSH. But it works when I restart from hetzner console and again after few hours it goes down.

I checked:

1. syslogs: there are lots of IPs trying to connect to machine but are being blocked by firewall (UFW).
2. I checked auth.log but I could not find any suspicious login.
3. I checked CPU utilization over time but that's also fine.

But now I don't have any clue what to look for. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Does `dmesg` shows anything unusual?

Comment: You say *hetzner console*, don't they have both a way to connect to your servers serial console, and a status indicator distinguishing "down" and "online" (just unresponsive)? Please [edit] your question to add the status determined through those methods, and the system log / journal lines the server recorded before becoming unresponsive.